# OpenMP Sparse Jacobi

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I'm trying to determine if there is a way to parallelize the Jacobi method using sparse matrix formats (specifically Compressed Row Format)

I have a working sparse matrix Jacobi. I don't know if I can place

!$OMP PARALLEL DO

Directives on the middle do loop because x is being both written to and read from. I guess the inner do loop can have it, but the same t is being overwritten so I don't know if it is possible there either. Am I overlooking something here? Thanks.

```
x(:) = 0
do p = 1, numIterations
    do i=1, n
        t=b(i)
        do j = IA(i), IA(i+1) - 1
            if j=i
                d=A(j)
            else
                t = t - A(j) * x(jA(j))
            end if
        end do
        x(i) = t/d
    end do
end do
```

Comment: Jacobi may be not the easiest method to parallelize - have you considered other types of solvers?

Comment: This looks like a bug "`if j=i`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true you have a dependency on `t` in the inner loop since it used as an accumulator. However, that also means you can have a private copy of `t` in each of the threads (since the arrays `A` and `x` are not being written in the loop, the value of `t` only depends on the value of `j`, which is also thread private).

The following should work:

```
x(:) = 0
do p = 1, numIterations
    do i=1, n
        t=0
        !$OMP PARALLEL DO
        !$OMP REDUCTION(+:t)
        do j = IA(i), IA(i+1) - 1
            if j=i
                d=A(j)
            else
                t = A(j) * x(jA(j))
            end if
        end do
        x(i) = (b(i)-t)/d
    end do
end do
```

Note that `d` can only be be written by one of the threads, so the variable can be shared betewen the threads, no loop-carried dependencies on `d`.

Comment: I'm not very confident with openMP but shouldn't you also add `!$OMP PRIVATE(t)` to ensure that there is no implicit serialization on t?

Comment: !$OMP REDUCTION does it automatically (see https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION), it makes all variables in the list private (otherwise it wouldn't make any sense)

Comment: Thank You for the response. Any chance that you can explain the reduction clause. Documentation is a bit fuzzy. "At the end of the reduction, the reduction variable is applied to all private copies of the shared variable, and the final result is written to the global shared variable." Does that mean that the values to be subtracted are held, then all subtracted from the global variable after the loop?

Comment: Well, it means that every thread has a private copy of `t`, let's call `t_pX` where `X in 0..THREADS`. `t_pX` is initialized with the value of `t` and every occurence of `t` inside the body of the loop will be replaced with `t_pX`. At the end of the loop, the reduction operation is applied (in this case `+`) so effectively this will be computed: `t = sum([t_pX for X in THREADS])`.